# Time Machine Backup accidentally unplugged, can't repair

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, backup, disk-utility, external-disk

I accidentally removed my Time Machine backup without ejecting. It didn't show up in Finder after I plugged it back in and Disk Utility cannot repair it. Disk Utility recommends reformatting the disk, but I want to make sure I'm doing it right. I don't really care about restoring the files because they are just old backups of my stuff (I only need a backup that works!)

In Disk Utility, I have a listing called "750.12 GB WD My Passport" and under that, I have a partition called "My Passport". I tried to Erase the "My Passport" partition, but Disk Utility couldn't find it. So now do I try to erase everything under the 750.12 GB WD My Passport option?

I'm pretty confident that the drive is not dying because it happened after I removed it without ejecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Reformat and partition the HD. When you unplugged the drive, you severely damaged the directory information on the 'My Passport' partition, rendering it unusable. If there is nothing of value on the drive, this is your best bet. In addition, make sure to reformat with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) selected.